# Excel 2003 XYZ Surface Chart like XY Line Chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2003

I have a grid of of values in Excel 2003 that form a surface.

Simplified example

```
Day 1   2   3   5
==================
1   0   0   2   1
2   0   2   3   0
3   0   0   1   0
```

In the column headings 4 is missing because there are no entries for 4 (i.e. all data is zero).

When I come to try and plot this as a surface chart in Excel 2003 it plots `1,2,3,5` as though they were series names and the same distance apart which distorts the surface (i.e. treats them as a category axis not a value axis)

Is there anyway to get excel to produce what amounts to an `xyz` value axis surface chart?

P.S. In the real data its not feasible to fill in the missing column numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Surface charts interpret X-Y data as discrete axes, and they cannot be set to continuous axes natively (see [this article](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=447) by the brilliant Jon Peltier). There are tools like [this one from Andy Pope](http://andypope.info/charts/3drotate.htm) which will plot a true X-Y-Z scatter plot, or [this file](http://www.doka.ch/Excel3Dscatterplot.htm) which does much of the same, but they are separate plugins and will not necessarily work with your data format (nor will they make surface plots).

Your best bet (no matter how impossible you say it is) is to fill in the empty series with all zeroes, as that will plot your data correctly.

Current:

[image: Current Surface Plot]

With Added Series:

[image: Improved Surface Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not using Excel 2003 I fear this may be no help at all (unless perhaps to clarify your requirement) but if the chart shown is what you seek then it may be helpful to know that this was with the addition of series for `4` with Series values: as shown (rather than a lot of zeros in source data):

[image: SO1834181 example]

*Edit*

I prefer time on the x-axis but if required on the z-axis:

[image: So1834181 second example]